# How to find parent window controll in child window using jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Currently i am using script in child window to access the asp button hdnbtnrefresh  placed in parent window

```
var btn = top.opener.document.getElementById("hdnbtnrefresh");
```

but it return null

Comment: Id in getElementById will not start from #.

Comment: As it is a ASP.NET Button, the generated id will be different than "hdnbtnrefresh". View source of the parent page and grab the id from there and use this id in the child window script.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use directly the jquery selector with id:

```
$("#hdnbtnrefresh")
```

For the parent nodes, you can play with parent()

```
$("#hdnbtnrefresh").parent()
```

Doc here:
http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Other way:

```
$('#hdnbtnrefresh', window.parent.document).html();
```

Comment: i want to get parent window control in child window.is that possible with 
    $("#hdnbtnrefresh")

Answer (score 0):

Try window.opener.$("#hdnbtnrefresh")

Happy coding!!!